# I lost a table name in my sqlite_sequence table. How do I re-instate it?

Tags: sqlite

It seems that when I revised a column definition (not the primary key column) in a table using the 'Edit Column' command on the Structure page under SQLite Manager, sqlite3 deleted that table name from its sqlite_sequence table. I tried to add it back in manually, but found that the seq number does not get updated on an addition into that lost table.

Does anyone know how to re-instate the lost table name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [sqlite_sequence documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) says:

> If the sqlite_sequence.seq value for an AUTOINCREMENT table is manually set to something other than an integer and there is a subsequent attempt to insert the or update the AUTOINCREMENT table, then the behavior is undefined.

However:

> If the sqlite_sequence row for an AUTOINCREMENT table does not exist when the AUTOINCREMENT table is updated, then a new sqlite_sequence row is created.

So you should not add a 'fake' entry to sqlite_sequence, but you can change it if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used the Export wizard to dump the file. Then pasted the sql back into the Execute window and ran it. Everything looks dandy now!